# Spring JUnit tests .. autowire not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit

Hoping for some help discovering why these tests throw errors..

I've written a Spring Boot RESTful app.  I have integration tests written in JUnit which work (reading the configuration from application.properties)

The Controller calls a class which contains the database access

Testing the controller works fine.. when I try to test the database access class directly.. I get a BindException Failed to bind properties under 'spring.datasource'

```
 @RequestMapping("/{source}/product")
Result prodBySource(@PathVariable String source, @RequestParam String prodId) throws Exception {
    logger.debug(String.format("GET Product %s from %s. ", source, prodId)) ;

    return productDb.getProd(prodId);

}
```

The productDb has

```
protected String getJson(String prodId) {
    MapSqlParameterSource params = new MapSqlParameterSource()
            .addValue("product_id", prodId);
    String jsonString = "{}" ; 

    String jsonString = jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(query, params, 
            (rs, rowNum) -> {
                return rs.getString("json_data") ; 

            });

    return jsonString;
}

public Result getProd(String prodId) {
    String jsonString = getJson(prodId);
    Object jsonNode = JsonPath.parse(jsonString).json();
    Result res = new Result(prodId, jsonNode) ; 
    return res;
}
```

The JUnit test has

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes= {ProductDb.class, AppConfig.class}) 
@TestPropertySource(locations = 
"classpath:/com/broadridge/adc/fasttests/product/application- 
fasttests.properties")
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="spring.datasource")
@Category(com.broadridge.adc.product.FastTests.class)
public class ProductDbTest implements FastTests {

@Autowired
ProductDb lipperProductDb ; 

@Test
public void getJson() throws Exception {


    Result json = 
     lipperProductDb.getProd("30027978") ; 
    Supplier<String> messageSupplier = () -> {
        return "Json can't be null";
    };
    Assert.notNull(json, messageSupplier);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you are autowiring interface rather than a implementation class. If you test DAO Layer should mock repository/dao object. No actual database call should be made during testing that layer rather autowiring the actual dao object you should mock the ProductDb and use **Mockito** when(), thenReturn().

```
 @RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
    @SpringBootTest(classes= {ProductDb.class, AppConfig.class}) 
    @TestPropertySource(locations = 
    "classpath:/com/broadridge/adc/fasttests/product/application- 
    fasttests.properties")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="spring.datasource")
    @Category(com.broadridge.adc.product.FastTests.class)
    public class ProductDbTest implements FastTests {

    @Mock
    ProductDb lipperProductDb ; 

    @Test
    public void getJson() throws Exception {
      Result resultJson = new Result()//some result object
      when(lipperProductDb.getProd("30027978")).thenReturn(resultJson);

        Result json = 
         lipperProductDb.getProd("30027978") ; 
        Supplier<String> messageSupplier = () -> {
            return "Json can't be null";
        };

        Assert.notNull(json, messageSupplier);
    }
```

Comment: In this case, I do want to make the database call.   It's an integration test.  However, I think that I should take advantage of that suggestion in the Controller tests, now that I have the DAO test running correctly

Comment: Ok, ProductDb is interface or concrete class

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why, but removing `@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="spring.datasource")` fixed the problem.